# Rename TFS 2013 Branch

Tags: tfs, branch, rename

We are using the release number for TFS branches. I have just created a new TFS branch with an upcoming release number. However, the client has since changed the release number which we would like to keep parallel TFS branch name.

The branch is new and no changes have been made to it yet.

What issues I can expect if I rename the branch? 
Is it better to create new branch from main with the new release number?

Comment: @ethesx, Thank you for improving my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A rename is a branch+delete under the covers.

You would be best creating a new branch with in tact history.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to know what will happen as it seems gray area when there is no checking in the created branch. I have gone with your option.